# Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x}{(x^2y + y^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Please help with: $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x}{x^2y + y^3}$$

The hint says let $u = x^2$

I have tried all the possible substitutions and manipulations on this ODE and I just can't separate variables or use any methods on this! What am I missing? The closest is that I have tried to flip everything so

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = xy + \frac{y^3}{x}$$

and tried to do Bernoulli's method on it but failed..

Thank you..

Comment: "The hint says let u = x^2" Did you use this hint at all?

Comment: it is really $$x^{2y}$$ in the denominator?

Comment: no it's (x^2)y, sorry!

Comment: Most probably that is $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{x}{x^2y + y^3}$$ and later on $$\frac{dx}{dy} = xy + \frac{y^3}{x}$$

Comment: yes, I used u = x^2 and then substituted on the LHS dy / (du/2x)

Answer (score 1):

Picking up from where you left, 
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = xy + \frac{y^3}{x}$$
or, $$x\frac{dx}{dy} = x^2y + y^3$$
Now put $u=x^2$ as the hint says. This gives $$\frac{du}{dy} = 2x\frac{dx}{dy}$$
Plugging that in, 
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{dy} = uy + y^3$$
Rearranging, 
$$\frac{du}{dy} - 2uy = 2y^3$$ which is a linear ODE which I'm sure you can solve.

(Here, $P(y) = -2y$ so the IF is $e^{\int P(y) dy} = e^{\int -2ydy} = e^{-y^2}$)

**EDIT:** (Reason why I multiplied by x)

I multiplied by $x$ because I would need a $du=2xdx$ for the substitution $x^2=u$. More over, it removes the term where both $x$ and $y$ appear together ($\frac{y^3}{x}$). The reasoning is quite similar to that for Bernoulli's method where you divide by $y^n$ and put $y^{-n+1} =t$ because it makes the last term (the one on the right hand side) "y-free" and the other parts match because $$\frac{d(y^{-n+1})}{dx} = (1-n)y^{-n}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and you already have $y^{-n}\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: I think you meant to say IF is $e^{\int(-2y)\,dy}=e^{-y^2}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks! Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you!!! What was your reasoning for multiplying x to the exn?? Because I just subtracted xy to try to force Bernoulli's method on it....

Comment: @kalmond I've edited my answer to include what you wanted. Have a look.

Comment: You're awesome thank you!!

Comment: @kalmond, if you are reasonably happy with this answer you should "accept" it. I you like this answer, you should upvote it. If you don't like it, however, don't feel pressurized to do so. I'm saying this only because it seems that you're new here. Cheers!